# Photoshop Scripting: iterating list of all layers withing the layerset is very slow

Tags: javascript, photoshop, layer, photoshop-script

The task that I'm trying to implement is very simple:

I need to get a list of all layers (one-level), within a specified layer set (group), and to write this list to a file.

The code is simple (and working) as well:

```
function indexCurrent(document){
    var log = new File(indexLocation+document.name+'.js');
    alert("Collecting data");
    var images = document.layerSets.getByName("Images").layers;
    var imagesLength = images.length;

    var layers = [];

    alert("Iterating " + imagesLength + " layers");

    for(var jj = 0, jL = imagesLength; jj < jL; jj++){
        layers.push('\t\t\'' + images[jj].name + '\'');
    }

    alert("Writing " + layers.length + " layers");

    log.open('w');
    log.write('\n\t\'' + document.name + '\': [\n' );
    log.write(layers.join(",\n"));
    log.write('\n\t]\n');
    log.close();
}
```

This code works, but for 150+ layers it takes hours between "Iterating" and "Writing" lines.

I have read all related questions here, but that doesn't help.

I'm sure that there should be much more efficient way for such a simple task.

I'm running Photoshop CS6 on Windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you execute this code? Where?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try switching from accessing the layers via the DOM to getting at them via the action manager.  I'm pretty sure you'll get better performance that way. I'm terrible with the action manager code so I can't give you a working example - just something to google :)

Answer (score 0):

Runs fine and fast for me, but you didn't state how large the source psd is.

Anyhoo, have a look here:
[Action Manager layer search](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2978016)

I can't run it as I'm running good old CS2. Ye-har!

Comment: he says there are 150+ layers and I know I've run into performance problems long before 150 layers :)  I reckon even 50 layers in the right PSD is enough to be noticeably slow.  I'm assuming he doesn't have the names of the layers in his layer set, so I'm not sure how much help that link will be.  But I'm almost certain there is a 'move next layer' command that will move through all the layers in the set via action manager. But you'll need to check after each 'move next' to make sure that you haven't moved out of the desired layer set.

Comment: Sorry, just looked at that link again - totally missed the first function in the script which is probably exactly what he needs :) Good find!